# Customize JSON serialization in Quarkus Smallrye GraphQL

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

How can the JSON serialization in Quarkus [Smallrye GraphQL](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-graphql) be customized? E.g. I want to omit null values from JSON:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": null
}
```

vs.

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

So far, I have tried the following solutions with no success:

- Writing a [CDI producer for ObjectMapper / JsonbConfig](https://lordofthejars.github.io/quarkus-cheat-sheet/#_json_marshallingunmarshalling)
- Implementing a [Smallrye EventingService](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-graphql/2.7.0/custom-json-deserializers/)

Debugging a little into the code I found that Eclipse Parsson seems to be used to serialize the response. Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Omitting fields that the client requested in a subselection would be against the GraphQL specification, so this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, in theory that makes sense to me. But: Isn't a missing key semantically equivalent to a null value? If so, wouldn't it be better to send a smaller response JSON? If there is a large number of null values, this can have a significant performance impact.

Comment: Null and missing aren't quite semantically equivalent IMO. Null means that there is no value, missing means that the client didn't request it. That said, of course, it would theoretically be possible to add a configuration option to enable skipping of nulls, but wouldn't it be better to simply handle the null properly on the client?

Comment: By a large number of null values, you mean how many in your case?

Comment: If you really think this would be useful, feel free to report it as an issue via GitHub (https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-graphql) so we can discuss it with a wider audience

Comment: Ok I've talked to a colleague and we've decided to report it https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-graphql/issues/2042 and he's gonna have a look at it. Feel free to watch that issue or add something to the discussion.